# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined Discord.js Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

at module.exports (/Users/beyoki/Desktop/Coding/8FE Bot/events/guild/message.js:8:37)

Making a discord bot, working on getting it to work inside my server, and any time i use my code for an embed

(code Below)

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: 'seed',
    description: "seed time baby, Whos ready?",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        const seedEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Seed Time!')
        .setDescription('Click on the reaction to let us know if you are able to seed with us')
        .setFooter('Made by Beyoki#9983')
        .setImage('https://imgur.com/4pD7GvP')
        message.channel.send({embeds: [newEmbed]});
    }
}
```

And the message handler code

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = ';';
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

    if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
}
```

Comment: `client.commands` is undefined. Use optional chaining (`= client?.commands?.get(cmd);`) or check each part (` = client && client.commands && client.commands.get(cmd);`).

Comment: to be simple `client` doesn't have a property `.commands`, you only did the part where you defined the `message` event. You still need to defined the `client.command` property to have a functionning command handler. (also you confused `newEmbed` and `seedEmbed` on your first code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client.command is not defined, not a issue by discord.js